# Is a question on contracts appropriate?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is money the right stack exchange in which to ask a question about whether a businesses refusal to sell a particular contract based on residency is allowed by law?

This is a contract for parking and impacts personal finance in the increased cost of the alternative contract they want to offer instead.

Comment: What type of contract is it and is there a bearing on personal finance?

Comment: Sounds more as a legal question to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks more like a legal question. ie Can a Business refuse to sell you a particular type of contract because of residency. They want to sell you something else that is more expensive.

If this is the question, then I don't think moeny is the right sight. A Business [unless there are regulations] is free to sell or not sell you something. As to whether there are any legal laws that will force the business to sell you would not be in the scope of this site even tough it affects money.

There are no SE site that I know of that would allow this question.